# php - words in database not found when they contain foreign language letters

Tags: php, mysql

In the admin section of my website's glossary, I wrote an ajax function which checks the mysql database for existing entries with the same term before the form is being inserted to avoid double entries.

The function works, but only when the term does not contain any foreign language characters. The website's main language is French, so there's a lot of these. The database tables are encoded in latin1_swedish_c1 (default).

**JS**

```
$('input[id=term]').live('focusout',function(){
        var element = $(this).attr('id');
        var term = $(this).val();
        if(term != ""){
        // alert(term);
        $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(2).load('ajax/term_chk.php', {'term':term}, function(data){
        $(this).html(data);
        });
        }
        });
```

**PHP**
term_chk.php calls the following function:

```
function checkTerm($term)
{
$qry = "select * from trm where term = '".addslashes($term)."' limit 1";
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
if(mysql_numrows($qry_res) > 0)
{
    $t = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);
    $checkStr = '<span style="background-color: #F00; padding: 1px 10px">ID '.$t['id'].'</span>';
} else {
    $checkStr = '<span style="background-color: #5BB26B; ; padding: 1px 10px">OK</span>';
}
return $checkStr;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you give us the ajax function you're using ?

Comment: @Baptiste Wicht - just added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. The symptoms might be explained by the character encoding of the webpage. If the webpage is UTF-8 but the MySQL connection character set is Latin-1, for example, then the query will not work because each multi-byte character will be interpreted as a series of characters.
2. `addslashes()` is not good enough protection against SQL injection. Use a database-connection-specific function such as `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Better still, update to PDO or the mysqli library; the mysql library is obsolete.
3. The name of the collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`, not `latin1_swedish_c1`.

Comment: I suspect that you are right re the character encoding (1). In order to solve this, do I need to reencode the database in UTF-8 ? If so, is there a way to proceed with this without the content being altered ? or is there an easier solution ?

Comment: It depends whether the content already stored in the database is stored as Latin-1 as intended, or is stored mis-encoded. If you can view the contents of the database using an application like phpMyAdmin then you will be able to get a better idea of what state the database contents are in. The best case scenario is that you just need to change the character sets of the database columns, and set your scripts to communicate with MySQL using the right character set with `SET NAMES`. If the data already stored is mis-encoded then there is a procedure you can follow to correct this.